# Mysql subquery how can i get only all records from Table1 and if no match found with Table2 still list them as null or something else?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1) I have two table:

```
+------                      +---------
topic                         mytask
+---------                   +---------
ID | What                    ID | TopicID
----------                   ------------
1  | A                        1 | 1
2  | B
```

2) I have SQL as below:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, b.id
FROM 
  topic a
JOIN (
 SELECT 
  b.id,b.topicid
 FROM 
  mytask b
) b on (b.topicid=a.id)
```

3) I have output as below (1 ROW ONLY):

```
ID | ID
-------
1  | 1
```

My expected output is as below (2 ROW, PRIORITY TO TOPIC BY LISTING THEM ALL) :

```
a.ID | b.ID
-------------
1    | MATCHED - OK - TAKE IT!!!
2    | NULL or what,ever...
```

How can i do that?

Comment: It surprises me that 'Google' could not find the answer to this one.

Comment: There was a BUG, if i have mytask table same record duplicate it creates wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a **left outer** join:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, b.id
FROM 
  topic a
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT 
  b.id,b.topicid
 FROM 
  mytask b
) b on (b.topicid=a.id)
```

and simplify the query to

```
SELECT 
  a.id, b.id
FROM 
  topic a
LEFT JOIN 
  mytask b ON b.topicid = a.id
```

Comment: Let's call it a left outer join, not an outer left join.

Comment: Removed my post / changed vote due to mistunderstanding - my apologies

Comment: @Simonatmso.net I still need to get my 'peer pressure' badge some time, I guess you just missed out on it too :) http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure